# Переход по кнопке из 1 фрагмента в другой который не содержится в контейнере

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать переход из 1 фрагмента в другой по кнопке не используя контейнер. У меня есть фрагмент и в нем есть кнопка при нажатии на эту кнопку надо переходить на другой фрагмент которого нет в контейнере

Answer (score 1):

Есть отличный мануал по работе с [фрагментами](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=RU). Из вашего вопроса не понятна суть того, что вы хотите реализовать.

> Для выполнения транзакций с фрагментами внутри операции (таких как
> добавление, удаление или замена фрагмента) необходимо использовать
> API-интерфейсы из FragmentTransaction. Экземпляр класса
> FragmentTransaction можно получить от объекта Activity следующим
> образом:
>
> FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
>
> FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
> fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
>
> После этого можно добавить фрагмент методом add(), указав добавляемый
> фрагмент и представление, в которое он должен быть добавлен. Например:
>
> ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
>
> fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
>
> fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: то что вы описали это работает в том случае если фрагмент находиться в контейнере, у меня такая ситуация что фрагмент живет отдельно от остальных и мне его надо вызывать по нажатию кнопки, по ссылке которую дали изучал уже информацию

Comment: добавьте более широкое описание в вопрос

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вам нужно и как. Посмотрите BottomSheetDialogFragment